# How easily and continuously monitoring CPU's temperature using only "sensors" (without a gui widget)?

Tags: sensors, lm-sensors

How easily and continuously monitoring the CPU's temperature using only "sensors"? That is, how continuously monitoring CPU's temperature without additional software (without a gui widget, for example) in a simple and friendly way?

Comment: Since you are using the lm-sensors tag, I'm thinking you are refering to the command `sensors` that comes with the lm-sensors package. is that correct? I always used to use a gnome panel applet called `gnome hardware monitor` to display graphs in the panel from lmsensors output. in your case, you will have to write a poller-n-parser that will call `sensors` periodically, parse the response, and do somthing with it to inform the user. I never did figure out a good means to do this after the gnome-3/unity fiasco.

Comment: You can get a device that fits in the cd/dvd drive bay,that has a probe and shows the temperature on an LCD screen.  But there perhaps isn't a great solution for where to put the probe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install "sensors" package.

Run "sensors-detect" to genereate the basic configuration.

**TIP:** Answer "yes" to everything!

Open a terminal and run "watch -n 1 sensors"!

**!!!!EXTRA!!!!** - Integrate with KDE/konsole:

Open a konsole and follow "Settings" -> "Configure Konsole ..." and uncheck "Use current window size on next startup."

**TIP:** To set an appropriate size to your konsole at startup follow "Settings" -> "Edit Current Profile..." -> "General" and set "Columns" and "Rows" as your taste (eg. 110 X 35)!

Open "System Settings" -> "Shortcuts" -> "Custom Shortcuts" and create on the tree a shortcut with the command "TerminalColumns=60;TerminalRows=18" -e watch -n 1 sensors".

**EG:**

1. "Second mouse button" -> "New" -> "Global Shortcut" -> "Command/URL";
2. Set the name "sensors";
3. In the "Trigger" tab to "Shortcut:" use "Alt+Shift+T";
4. In the tab "Command/URL:" use "konsole -p "TerminalColumns=60;TerminalRows=18" -e watch -n 1 sensors"

Comment: nice. glad you got what you were looking for. If you ever find a gui widget, let us know.

Comment: @Frank Thomas. You can use "conky"! It sounds interesting, but I just want to monitoring the temperature of my CPU in some occasions and nothing else! http://www.galaxius.org/doc/conky.html http://www.galaxius.org/download/conky/conky.png

Comment: NOTE: Unfortunately I haven't found a command to hide the konsole's scrollbar too! It would be great if there was one!