# High load over my CPU (and high temperature) when running “plasmashell.”

Tags: vmware-workstation, cpu-usage, kde-plasma-5, manjaro

The "plasmashell" ("/usr/bin/plasmashell") is causing an high load over my CPU (10~40%) (and high temperature). I've looked at several topics and not found any effective solution.

The forum "https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=121533" has several considerations, but no actual solution or workaround.

Apparently this is a bug. Some workaround?

```
Distro: MANJARO AMD64
UI: KDE5

Software:

KDE Plasma Version: 5.7.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.25.0
Qt Version: 5.7.0
Kernel Version: 4.4.19-1-MANJARO
OS Type: 64-Bit

Hardware:

Processors: 8 x Intel Core i7-3610QM @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,6 GiB of RAM
```

Thanks!

**!!! UPDATE !!!** Who is doing plasmashell rise in CPU usage is VMware Workstation. When we start a virtual machine soon after the plasmashell rise in CPU usage (image below). The inverse is also true. When we turned off the virtual machine the plasmashell back to consume no more than 2%! **Any idea what can be done?**

**NOTE:** This thread is also here "https://forum.manjaro.org/t/plasmashell-kde-high-load-over-my-cpu/8645". If there is a solution I will post here too!

[image]

Comment: You are negated and the person does not explain why. You want some more information? What is wrong? Please explain!

Comment: I didn't cast the downvote, but what are you expecting exactly? That someone here magically knows why plasmashell is generating a high CPU load while the internet is littered with pages without proper answers? Good, specific questions get good specific answers, answering a vague question is very difficult and SU is not really the place for turn-by-turn debugging.

Comment: What happens @mtak is I do not really know too much information about the issue  (I'm a little lost on this problem). What I know so far is that the "plasmashell" is rising in CPU consumption (and that's the problem) and I do not know how to fight this problem or even diagnose the causes and so I'm asking here. What kind of information I can provide you to be clearer?

Comment: `strace` is always a good place to start to check why a processing is consuming a lot of CPU. At least you'll know if it's something to do with interaction with the rest of the system or if it's something internal in the application.

Comment: Okay! I use the following command "killall plasmashell && strace -e trace=open,stat,read,write plasmashell &> plasmashell_strace.txt" which generated 53MiB of data. What should I look for? (NOTE: I appreciate iif you remove the negative! Thanks!)

Comment: If you complain about downvotes, more will come. If you’ve recently worked with Windows, you need to keep in mind that this load would mean 31.8% / 8 = 3.975% over there. It’s really not that much. Do you have anything interactive that integrates with the shell (widgets etc) running?

Comment: @EduardoLucio As I already stated in the first comment, I didn't cast the downvote. Usually, when you're not interacting with an application, it's not doing much. If it does a lot of stuff when you're not using it, that'll be the problem. For effective performance troubleshooting you need a lot of theoretical background in OS operations and application design, so if the strace output doesn't mean anything to you, it might be better to submit a bug report to the developers and hope they can fix it for you.

Comment: @mtak Sorry for the confusion! But I just can not understand that "downvote"! I am not opposing to make the suggested improvements. I'll do the procedure you suggested. Thank you very much!=D

Comment: "Downvote" means that your question was voted -1. Check the help center for more information on voting on questions and answers.

Comment: @mtak Apparently, the cause of "excessive" CPU load (plasmashell) has to do with vmware (see update above).

Comment: @mtak I know '"Downvote" means that your question was voted -1' I just can not understand why certain members of our community insist in MONOCRATICALLY "downvotes" you without even justify the reason. There are days I've been following and enriching this post. That's not fair! I have contributed a lot to the "superuser" community! This really discourages me!

Comment: FWIW, we ran into this at work and it turns out it's the vmware tray icon.  If you kill the vmware-tray process after you start up the VMs, then everything is fine.  There is an option to say that you don't ever want the icon, but that doesn't appear to be honored and VMWare fires it up anyways. :-(

Answer (score 0):

CPU load causes high temperature. This is one of the problems I have had with the high load on my CPU.

Below I present a "workaround" for Manjaro (my distro) and some extra content.

**Controlling the CPU temperature (power saving too =D)!**

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-power-savings-setup-update-20160724/1445

**Monitoring the CPU temperature:**

[How easily and continuously monitoring CPU's temperature using only "sensors" (without a gui widget)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1116313/how-easily-and-continuously-monitoring-cpus-temperature-using-only-sensors-w)